Pip/python unable to find boost under Windows 11 in virtual env
I'm trying to install vina package in virtual conda environment. Everything goes fine until pip install vina. This ends with following error:
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [63 lines of output]
  fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
  Version found 1.2.5 (from __init__.py)
  running egg_info
  creating vina. Egg-info
  writing vina. Egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to vina.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to vina.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to vina.egg-info\top_level.txt
  writing manifest file 'vina.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  Boost library is not installed in this conda environment.

But I have boost installed, I executed mamba install -c conda-forge numpy swig boost-cpp sphinx sphinx_rtd_theme. I also have boost_1_82 installed and added to system PATH. I was trying to list dependencies using johnnydep vina but it also filed with Boost library location was not found!
So my question is how to fix it? How can I set correctly reference to boost so my conda virtual env will find it?
Edit:
It is solely Windows problem, the very same commands work perfectly fine under Ubuntu 22.04. So as a workaround I use WSL, but if you have any clue how to solve it natively under Windows, I will leave this question open.

The direct cause of this is that boost includes from conda-forge on windows land in $CONDA_PREFIX/Library/include instead of $CONDA_PREFIX/include.
The solution is to change in setup.py the line
def locate_boost():
    """Try to locate boost."""
    if in_conda():
        data_pathname = os.environ["CONDA_PREFIX"]
        include_dirs = data_pathname + os.path.sep + 'include'
        library_dirs = data_pathname + os.path.sep + 'lib'

to
def locate_boost():
    """Try to locate boost."""
    if in_conda():
        data_pathname = os.environ["CONDA_PREFIX"]
        include_dirs = data_pathname + os.path.sep + 'Library' + os.path.sep + 'include'
        library_dirs = data_pathname + os.path.sep + 'Library' + os.path.sep + 'lib'

But the underlying issue is, that vina python bindings are not compatible with windwos. Even if you fix the boost issue, there are further problems.
It is not apparent from PyPi, but on github, we can see:

Python bindings for Python 3 (Linux and Mac)

